# Copy&Paste betwen different workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to paste something from "wb" to "wb1", but it just open "wb2".. I tried 2 different ways, but still not working. Any idea? Thanks.

```
Sub ()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook


Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("\\Homeshare\Home2.w1.xlsm")


wb.Worksheets("Sheets1").Range("B50").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
wb1.Worksheets("Production").Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste


End Sub
```

---

```
Sub ()
      Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook


ScreenUpdating = False

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("\\Homeshare\Home2\w1.xlsm")

wb.Worksheets("Sheets1").Range("B50").Copy
wb1.Worksheets("Production").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `wb.Worksheets("Sheets1").Range("B50").Copy wb1.Worksheets("Production").Range("A1")`

Comment: Try removing  Paste:=xlPasteFormats, just leave it at.PasteSpecial

Comment: Ricardo, many thanks. Now its working :)